# How to process json requests in lumen 5.8

Tags: php, json, lumen

I have json to login as follows:

```
{
"email":"mypersonaldata@gmail.com"
"password":"12345"
}
```

I can catch the json on the Controller by using `$content = $request->getContent();`
I want the json to be validated with

```
        //validate incoming request 
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }
```

Please help how I do that, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Hello friend you can see the documentation you will understand easily
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication refer.